# How do I update my Flask app's data?

Tags: python, flask, terminal

I am building a simple website using Python and Flask. I have noticed when I run the following command in terminal:

```
sudo python app.py
```

It sets everything up and makes my website accessible in a web browser from a local port. My problem is that my Flask `app.py` file does some web scraping and displays the results in the website when it is accessed.

Sadly, it seems this web scraped data does not update every time a person visits my website. Instead the web scraping code seems to run just once when I enter `sudo python app.py` and thus the results when one visits the URL are static. I would prefer `app.py` to run every time someone visits the site to get the most up to date, live scraped data. Is this possible and how would I do it with flask and python?

My `app.py` contains:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import praw
import datetime
from operator import attrgetter
import sys
import numpy as np

class Post:
    def __init__(self, subreddit):
        self.subreddit = subreddit


class HotPost:
    def __init__(self, subreddit, ):
        self.subreddit = subreddit


reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='myClientId',
                     client_secret='myClientSecret',
                     user_agent='pythonscript:com.example.hotandrisingcheckerandbarker:v0.1 (by /u/myusername)',
                     username='myusername',
                     password='mypassword')
subredditsToScan = ["Art", "videos", "worldnews"]
svm = joblib.load('modelSvm.pkl')
trendingPosts = []

for subreddit in subredditsToScan:
    for submission in reddit.subreddit(subreddit).hot(limit=150):

        trendingPosts.append(Post(subreddit))

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    #return "Flask App!"
    return render_template(
        'list.html',name=len(trendingPosts))

@app.route("/hello/<string:name>/")
def hello(name):
    return render_template(
        'list.html',trendingPosts=trendingPosts)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
```

Comment: What's in `app.py`?

Comment: app.py containts all my code that scrapes the websites as well as @app.route("/hello/<string:name>/") and the hello function def that tells the site what .html page to show them

Comment: Describing it abstractly isn't very helpful. Please [edit] your question and add the most important parts as a [mcve].

Comment: added this, although this is less to do with my specific code and more to do with the architecture and use of flask to deploy a website so not sure my code is gonna add much insight into the answer, but perhaps i am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load the page, the only part of your code that gets run is whatever is in the function attached to the relevant route. The part where you build `trendingPosts` only runs one time when you start the server.

If you move your `for` loop inside `index()` you should get the behaviour you're looking for:

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    for subreddit in subredditsToScan:
        for submission in reddit.subreddit(subreddit).hot(limit=150):
            trendingPosts.append(Post(subreddit))

    return render_template(
        'list.html',name=len(trendingPosts))
```